# Issue in launching minikube on mac

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes. I am trying to launch a kubernetes cluster in my local mac machine. I am using following command to launch Kubernetes:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

I am getting following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/kubectl is version 1.14.7, and is incompatible with Kubernetes 1.17.0. 
You will need to update /usr/local/bin/kubectl or use 'minikube kubectl' to connect with this cluster
```

Now while executing following command:

```
minikube kubectl
```

It is not doing anything, just showing basic commands along with their usages.

And while trying to upgrade kubetctl it is showing it is already up to date.

I have not found any solution for this. Any idea regarding how to fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

The best solution for you is to [update kubectl manually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-macos). To perform this you need to download the binary:

https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

Change permissions of kubectl to be executable:

```
$ chmod +x ./kubectl
```

And move to /usr/local/bin/ overwriting the old one.

```
$ sudo mv ./kubectl $(which kubectl)
```

To check the effects, run:

```
$ kubectl version
```

Comment: `sudo mv ./kubectl $(which kubectl)` is perfect.

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede perfect addition to the solution. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you have already upgraded and got the same error, try below

```
brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Best choice to upgrade your minikube, (and `kubernetes-cli`). Current latest releases of kubectl is `1.17.0`, and minikube `1.6.1`.

```sh
brew upgrade minikube
brew upgrade kubernetes-cli
```

Other option will be to run specific version of kubernetes in minikube.

```sh
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --kubernetes-version=1.14.7
```

Similar error message I got while using kubectl 1.17 against kubernetes 
installed with `--kubernetes-version=1.14.7`

```sh
/usr/local/bin/kubectl is version 1.17.0, and is incompatible with Kubernetes 1.14.7. You will need to update /usr/local/bin/kubectl or use 'minikube kubectl' to connect with this cluster
```

Comment: `minikube` is no more cask, its regular [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/minikube.rb) now.

Comment: @OlegButuzov, thanks for your response. I tried both commands, it seems they are already up to date. So still getting the same issue

Comment: last version of kubectl distributed via brew is `1.17.0`, but you have `1.14.7`, so most probably kubectl isn't brewed, but from somewhere else. You can try `brew link kubernetes-cli`

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case the `cli-1.14.*` was installed by *Docker Desktop* (you can check in its *"About"* menu). –  But am not sure if I should handle the upgrade with `brew` or if I should update *Docker Desktop*.. 

Comment: The (complicated) solution to keep just one Client version on the system is to uninstall DockerDesktop (Stable; max: 1.14.8), save images and export containers that you want to preserve, and then [reinstall DockerDesktop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#switch-between-stable-and-edge-versions) (Edge; the beta version).

Comment: The (easy) solution was to `brew remove minikube kubectl` and `brew install kubectl minikube`; it fixed the `kubectl` client version ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

Matching both the client and server versions fixed issue,

```
➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.5", GitCommit:"20c265fef0741dd71a66480e35bd69f18351daea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:16:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Client version: v1.15.5

Server version: v1.18.0

So update client version using,

```
➜  ~ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/<version-here>/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl
```

for installing v1.18.0,

```
➜  ~ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.18.0/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl
```

then,

1. `➜  ~ chmod +x ./kubectl`
2. `➜  ~ sudo mv ./kubectl $(which kubectl)`

Now check version,

```
➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:50:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime hyperkit link might be wrong and pointing to old version, such issues can be fixed in mac by

> brew link --overwrite hyperkit